next-auth CredentialsProvider returning strange error
so I've been using next-auth for a couple years now and am trying to dive into using the CredentialsProvider option for email/password authentication. I'm relatively new to import x from "y" as opposed to const x = require("y") so I'm not sure if it's an error there or what, but I'm receiving the following error -
⨯ pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js (12:9) @ CredentialsProvider
 ⨯ TypeError: next_auth_providers_credentials__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a function
...  10 |     },
  11 |     providers: [
> 12 |         CredentialsProvider({
     |         ^
  13 |             name: 'Credentials',
  14 |             credentials: {
  15 |                 email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },

My code for reference:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { connect } from '../../../utils/db/connect';
import { verifyPassword } from '../../../utils/hashing/verifyPassword';

export default NextAuth({
    session: {
        jwt: true,
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const { email, password } = credentials;
                const { db  } = await connect();

                const users = db.collection('users');
                const user = await users.findOne({ email });

                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error('No user found');
                }

                const isValid = await verifyPassword(password, user.password);

                if (!isValid) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
                }

                return { id: user._id, name: user.name, email: user.email };
            }
        })
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/login',
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt(token, user) {
            if (user) {
                token.id = user.id;
            }

            return token;
        },
        async session(session, token) {
            session.user.id = token.id;
            return session;
        }
    }
})

If you've got any idea what I'm doing wrong, please let me know!
